# Why does a 16 bit depth photograph export as 48 bit depth?

Tags: darktable, file-format, bit-depth, png, windows-10

When exporting a PNG file of a photograph as **16 bit depth** in Darktable, its Windows 10 file information ends up saying it has **48 bit depth**!

Similarly, the default 8 bit depth when exported comes out being 32 bit depth according to Windows.

Why the mismatch, and which one is the industry standard when selling sRGB photographs, 8 bit or 16 bit?

Darktable:

[image]

Windows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because the images are colour so they have 16 bits channel for red, 16 bits for green and 16 bits for blue.

```
16+16+16=48
```

About selling: first you should check the stock photo sites, they are usually very good indicator. And AFAIK the usual practice is to sell 8 bits (24 bits) photos. If you have 16 bits photos you can ask for more money

Comment: Thanks, could you edit with comments about whether 8-bit or 16-bit is the industry standard? Does it depend on the source camera, what to know?

Comment: @user610620, check my edited answer. ANd next time ask one question.

Comment: @user610620 Which imaging *industry*? News/Editorial? Fine Art? eBay product photography? High end catalog product photography? Newspaper sales inset product photography? Web based advertising?

Comment: You can ask for more money for anything. That doesn't mean you'll get it. Sometimes asking for more means those asking for less get the business and you get nothing.

Comment: @MichaelC, right, you may ask and not get them. But you can communicate with customer the value (16 bits) you provide

Comment: @RomeoNinov but the bit depth by itself tells you nothing.  You can easily convert 8 bits to 16 just by adding 8 zero bits to the end of each pixel value, but the quality of the image doesn't change.